# Formula too long and applies to only one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an INDEX MATCH formula,

```vb
Sub AAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHH()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = "=INDEX('\\data\Documents\[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2='\\data\Documents\[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$E:$E)*(J2='\\data\Documents\[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$J:$J),0))"
End Sub
```

The INDEX formula is too long so it doesn't work.
The formula only applies to E2 and not for E3; E4; etc.

I was thinking of shortening it with changing the name to a variable so as the name changes every week it makes it easier.

```vb
Sub AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHH()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Dim lr As Long
    
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = "=INDEX('H:\Documents\[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2='H:\Documents\[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$E:$E)*(J2='H:\Documents\[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$J:$J),0))"
End Sub
```

I changed the path so now it is not too long.

I need to make it apply to each cell depending on the row because now it only puts results for E2 and J2 so I've the same thing all my R column.

```vb
Sub cacontinue2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
    mnt = InputBox("Filename")
    mnt2 = "H:\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx"
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ty = ("=INDEX(mnt!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=mnt!$E:$E)*(J2=mnt!$J:$J),0))")
    ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty
```

Now I've an update value window opening for each value.

Comment: I don't think that formula being "too long" is an issue, formulas that are twice as long work perfectly fine.

Comment: I've the output unable to set the formula array property of the range class it happens when you've got over 255 characters in an array formula as it seems  , nonetheless i need to make the name of the file easy to change.

Comment: Ok that's new for me, is putting the formula in the OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx and then cutting it and pasting it an option ?

Comment: what do you mean ? putting it in the file itself ? as it will change each week i'll need to do it everyweek if I could have one formula with an inputbox for the filename it would be easier

Comment: I think that having a macro that opens a file based on the inputbox, puts the array formula in the newly opened file then cuts it from the OPEN ORDERS file to the target workbook might be easier. There are already answers for that kind of issue as well f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405278/open-a-file-with-user-input-in-excel-vba

Comment: i've changed my formula now i just need it to be relative to it's cell and not only E2 & J2

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196290/error-1004-when-trying-to-use-formulaarray-replace-trick-does-not-work/51197173#51197173

Comment: Thanks i'll look into it ! But my main problem now is that the output of the formula is only for E2 & J2 so my column as the same result everywhere

Comment: I think you want E2 and J2 to be variable. So use a variable for it. Something like `Dim cell1, cell2 As String
cell1 = "E2"` and then concatanate the strings like:
`myFormula = '"=INDEX('mnt2Sheet 1'!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(" & cell1 & "='mntSheet 1'!$E:$E)*(" & cell2 & "='H:\Documents\mntSheet 1'!$J:$J),0))"`

Comment: @ffonz thanks ! but how do i make the variable go from e2 to e945 for example ? and i should just replace E2 by the variable ?

Comment: @ffonz `Sub cacontinue3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim celle As String
Dim cellj As String
Dim mnt, mnt2 As String
celle = "E2"
cellj = "J2"
mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "H:\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx"
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = "=INDEX('mnt2Sheet 1'!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(" & celle & "='mntSheet 1'!$E:$E)*(" & cellj & "='H:\Documents\mntSheet 1'!$J:$J),0))"
End Sub`
This gives me the same output as before

Comment: Surround the code with a for-loop. Search for "for loop vba" and you will find loads of examples. Use an integer as a counter from 2 to 945 and insert it in your string. It is a good habbit to place the content of your for-loop inside a new method if it is more than 5 to 10 lines (approx).

Comment: @ffonz Thanks for the loop idea it went through my mind but wanted to make it work like this without a loop cause i'm not used to it for now , I've managed to make it work but if you have an idea why a update value window pops up asking me to select the excel file it would be nice to know how to stop it.

Comment: coz you have in your code `mnt = InputBox("Filename")`. The method `InputBox` shows an InputBox. If you don't want it, replace it with a hard-coded string (or just remove variable `mnt`).

Comment: no it's not an input box it's the windows file manager that pops asking me to click on the excel file for everyrow

Comment: I think that if you want your formula to apply to each cell depending on the row, then use [R1C1 notation](https://excelchamps.com/blog/r1c1-reference-style/). Record your formula with a macro and see what you get.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I get this `Range("R2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=INDEX('[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!C18,MATCH(1,(RC[-8]='[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!C10)*(RC[-13]='[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!C5),0))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R145")
    Range("R2:R145").Selec` but i was told not to use select and i don't know how to put this one in the code i already did

Comment: From what you recorded, you just need the formula part. Notice that using macro recorder, now your formula is in R1C1 notation. For example `RC[-8]='[OPEN ORDERS` will be referenced always to a cell in same row where you apply the formula, but 8 columns to the left. Same with `RC[-13]='[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018` (same row, but 13 columns to the left). Now you just have to modify your code to use this formula and see if it works. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51196473/9199828) to activate R1C1 notations before applying formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub cacontinue100()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
Dim xWb As Workbook

ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\[" & mnt & ".xlsx]Sheet 1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("\\klxdata\homeshares\klxaero\nbi\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ty = Array("=INDEX(" & mnt & "!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=" & mnt & "!$E:$E)*(J2=" & mnt & "!$J:$J),0))")
ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
xWb.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```